# communication between multiple EmberJs components

Tags: ember.js

Please have look in this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ivOyiZa/1/edit

This panel accordion allows to open multiple panels. I want an accordion that opens only one panel at a time. If there is a panel opened and user clicks on another panel, opened panel must be closed before opening new panel. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO it's a bit overkill to make a component the header and body, because it create separate view and controllers for each. I'd advice you to use partials instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ivOyiZa/22/edit)

I added the currently opened `emberAccordionItemView` to the `EmberAccordionComponent`. I also added an observer to the `emberAccordionItemView` to autoClose everything that is not the `openedItemView`.

```
App.EmberAccordionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  openedItemView: null,
  emberAccordionItemView: Ember.View.extend({    
    expanded: false,
    autoClose: function() {
      if(this.get('parentView.openedItemView') !== this) {
        this.set('expanded', false);   
      }
    }.observes('parentView.openedItemView')
  })
  ....
```

The click event in `EmberAccordionHeaderComponent` now sets the `openedItemView` to the `EmberAccordionComponent`

```
App.EmberAccordionHeaderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({  
  classNames: ['ember-accordion-header'],  
  click: function() {
    this.set('parentView.parentView.openedItemView', this.get('parentView'));

    // here we toggle the emberAccordionItemView.expanded property
    this.toggleProperty('parentView.expanded');  
  }
});
```